# ImageView is null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, imageview

I've got a little problem concerning an ImageView in my Activity. I'm trying to set teamLogo1 and teamLogo2 to logos using Picasso. Following Error occurs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.pd13user.hltvmatches, PID: 28179
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pd13user.hltvmatches/com.example.pd13user.hltvmatches.MatchDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.pd13user.hltvmatches.MatchDetailActivity.onCreate(MatchDetailActivity.java:65)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

After adding

```
if(teamLogo1 != null && teamLogo2 != null){...}
```

it seems that both ImageViews are null. Here's my Code:

```
    package com.example.pd13user.hltvmatches;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MatchDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent i = getIntent();
    ImageView teamLogo1;
    ImageView teamLogo2;
    TextView team1;
    TextView team2;
    TextView time;
    TextView event;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("date"));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_detail);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_match_detail, null);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


        teamLogo1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.teamlogo1);
        teamLogo2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.teamlogo2);
        team1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1);
        team2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team2);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        event = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event);

        String[] data = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("data");

        /*if(teamLogo1 != null && teamLogo2 != null) {
            Picasso.with(this).load(data[4]).resize(50, 50).into(teamLogo1);
            Picasso.with(this).load(data[5]).resize(50, 50).into(teamLogo2);
        }*/

        teamLogo1.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
        teamLogo2.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);

        System.out.println(data[4] + "\n" + data[5]);

        team1.setText(data[1]);
        team2.setText(data[2]);
        time.setText(data[0]);
        event.setText(data[3]);
    }

}
```

I've tried findViewById without inflating a View as well (which works just fine for my TextViews, as they show properly without any exceptions) which produces the same exception.

EDIT: Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.pd13user.hltvmatches.MatchDetailActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="137dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_match_detail">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/teamLogo1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/teamLogo2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/time"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/vs"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/teamLogo1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/versus"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/teamLogo2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/vs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/event"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teamLogo2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/time" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also provide us with your XML code

Comment: please provide your xml file

Comment: Added the XML code

Comment: Have you tried setting the src attribute in XML just to see if it display anything or not?

Comment: Does your resource file exist?

Comment: Yes, I did that, it does display the src, I just can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `id` properly on `java` file. It should be same as you written on layout `xml` file. You used `v.findViewById(R.id.teamlogo1);` instead of `teamLogo1`. And if layout xml file is same as you provided on `setContentView()` method, then remove inflating view, just use `findViewById(R.id.teamLogo1)`.

Comment: Already tried the latter, produces the same exception. The first tip doesn't work either way as well.

Comment: Did you used these - `teamLogo1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.teamLogo1);
 teamLogo2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.teamLogo2);`

Comment: Use your view's id as same on `xml` layout file. Remember you used `teamLogo1` and `teamLogo2` on your xml file. id is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch. A typo. I feel dumb now.

I used teamlogo1 with a small l instead of teamLogo1 with a capital L.

Answer (score 0):

remove `v` from the start of `v.findViewById(R.id.teamlogo1);`

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.teamLogo1);` this should work if you xml file is exactly this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
teamLogo1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.teamlogo1); 
teamLogo2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.teamlogo2);
```

Replace above two lines by these below two.

```
teamLogo1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.teamLogo1); 
teamLogo2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.teamLogo2);
```

Also you are not using I'd proper ,in XML teamLogo1 but in Java you are using teamlogo1 and same for teamlogo2.

Answer (score 0):

you are showing `xml` `Showin` so that `xml` shows inside the `activity_match_detail` so you don't need to  `inflate` the `layout`

just use as Normal element.

so replace with following code .

```
teamLogo1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.teamlogo1);
teamLogo2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.teamlogo2);
```